# Fixed top navigation disappears after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using Chrome, and when i reload my page it brings me to the point of the page i was before reloading. So when i already scrolled half of the page and i reload it, chrome brings me back to where i scrolled to before.

I got a fixed nav-bar on my page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
var  mn = $(".top-menu");
mns = "main-nav-scrolled";
hdr = $('header').height();

$(window).scroll(function() {
if( $(this).scrollTop() > hdr) {
mn.addClass(mns);
} else {
mn.removeClass(mns);
}
});
});
```

The navigation works, but when i reload the page it is dissapeared until i start scrolling again. Someone has any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Makes no sense. If you refresh the site in jsfiddle it does not bring you back to the point you have scrolled to before in the result window, so I coulndn't even show you the problem there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like that :

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(window).scroll(sticky_nav());
    sticky_nav(); // Force the first call on refresh 
});

function sticky_nav() {
    var  mn = $(".top-menu");
    mns = "main-nav-scrolled";
    hdr = $('header').height();

    if( $(this).scrollTop() > hdr) {
        mn.addClass(mns);
        } else {
        mn.removeClass(mns);
    }
}
```